# Display course with which we earned the most

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to learn some new skills in oracle sql so I was searching for some examples on web. I found this one, with 6 questions. I made all the tables and all the connections. I knew how to solve 5 questions but this, last one seems too hard for me.

I don't know how to display from tables with which course we earned the most. We actually have to check which preson visited which course and than which person paid which bill, also what type of price was on that bill (normal od student).

I would be realy happy if you guys could help me.

Thanks a lot!

Here is printscreen of my E-R model and code of my oracle sql:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaprD.jpg,
http://pastebin.com/c1CqF3K8

If you don't understand anything despite my bad english or anythning else, feel free to ask. I would be realy happy if we could solve that problem!

Comment: What have you tried? and how it it failing?
Use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) rather than pastebin so others can immediately try your SQL environment.

Comment: @mdahlman well actually that is my problem. I have started few days ago and I don't know how to challenge with that problem, so that is why I am one here, looking for some help of you guys.

Comment: I wish you good luck with it. But if you're not able to point query that's failing, then stackoverflow may not be the right place to ask the question.

Comment: @mdahlman Like i said, I am tottaly new at oracle sql, so I don't know how to face that problem. I was solving only questions with two tables. This question looks really hard to beginner. I came on here because I was hoping someone would explain me my problem and  help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this query. I used visitor's age to check type of bill, because from your design it wasn't possible. In column bill.fk_student you store something weird which gives no valuable information, 
also it's not clear how table bill joins with other tables. Anyway here you have example how to build multiple joins and manipulate with data:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c23437/1)

```
with data as (
  select c.id id, c.name, l.id lid, fk_visitor vid, p.price
    from course c 
      join lecture l on l.fk_course = c.id
      join visiting vg on vg.fk_lecture = l.id
      join visitor vr on vr.id = vg.fk_visitor
      join price p on p.fk_course = c.id
        and price_type = case when vr.age < 25 then 'student' else 'normal' end )
select id, name, sum(price) income 
  from data
  group by id, name
  order by income desc
```

Output:

```
        ID NAME                     INCOME
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Programming                1170 
         6 Acting                      500 
         2 Mathematic                  440 
         4 Diving                      310 
         5 Driving                     200 
         3 Swimming                    200
```

To get most lucrative course just get first row from this output using `rownum`, also possible solutions with functions `row_number()` or `rank()`.